# TextAlignmentStyle .natural doesn't work with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need my text to change depend on **text language** not depend on App language
if it's RTL language like Arabic the text alignment should be RTL
if it's LTR language like English the text alignment should be LTR

I tried to import UILabel from UIKit because SwiftUI doesn't have .natural and .justified
like this

```
struct LabelAlignment: UIViewRepresentable {
var text: String
var textAlignmentStyle : TextAlignmentStyle
var width: CGFloat
var fontSize: CGFloat
var textColorName: String

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment(rawValue: textAlignmentStyle.rawValue)!
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width
    label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    label.textColor = UIColor(named: textColorName)
    return label
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
    uiView.text = text
    if let customFont = UIFont(name: "Almarai-Regular", size: fontSize)  {
        uiView.font =  UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .headline).scaledFont(for: customFont)
        uiView.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true


     }    }
 
}

enum TextAlignmentStyle : Int{
     case left = 0 ,center = 1 , right = 2 ,justified = 3 ,natural = 4

}
```

then I use it like this

```
   HStack {

      LabelAlignment(text: "My text" , textAlignmentStyle: . natural, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30, fontSize: 15, textColorName: "color3")
                                    .padding(.horizontal,5)
                                    .layoutPriority(1.0)
                                    .foregroundColor(.textColor3)
                                    .regularStyle(size: 15)
                                    .padding([.bottom,.top], 8)           
                            }
```

it working great with left ,center , right and justified
but it won't work with natural

Comment: Is this actually a problem in SwiftUI? It uses”leading” and “trailing” for multilineTextAlignment, not left and right, because leading/trailing are relative. That is, “leading” is the left edge in English but the right edge in Arabic. (I haven’t tested with any RTL languages myself, but if this doesn’t work then it’s a SwiftUI bug)

Comment: Correct I notice it when I change the App language , I find a better solution , I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

As Adam mention
if you follow my old answer it won't work correctly if you change the App language

The correct way is

```
struct LabelAlignment: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text: String
    var width: CGFloat
    var fontSize: CGFloat
    var textColorName: String
    var detectLangauge = ""

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {

    let label = UILabel()

    
    if detectLangauge == "Arabic" || detectLangauge == "العربية" {
        label.textAlignment = .right
    }else {
        label.textAlignment = .left
    }
    
    
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width
    label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    label.textColor = UIColor(named: textColorName)
    return label
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
    uiView.text = text
    if let customFont = UIFont(name: "Almarai-Regular", size: fontSize)  {
        uiView.font =  UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .headline).scaledFont(for: customFont)
        uiView.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true


      }    }
}
```

Then use it like this

```
 LabelAlignment(text: "My text", width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30, fontSize: 15, textColorName: "color3",detectLangauge:detectLangauge)
```

it will work as .natural

---

**Old answer** :
I found a solution with pure SwiftUI

First you need to add these code

import Foundation
import NaturalLanguage

```
extension String {
func detectedLanguage() -> String? {
    let recognizer = NLLanguageRecognizer()
    recognizer.processString(self)
    guard let languageCode = recognizer.dominantLanguage?.rawValue else { return nil }
    let detectedLanguage = Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: languageCode)
    return detectedLanguage
}
}
```

then you need a @State value to save the result of detectedLanguage()

```
@State private var detectLangauge = ""
```

after that check the result of text by using

```
 detectLangauge = "your text".detectedLanguage()
```

you can check your text language onApper() or after get result from API

then you need to add

```
 Text("Your Text")
  .multilineTextAlignment(detectLangauge == "Arabic" ? .trailing : .leading)
```